# хранение множества категорий в базе

Tags: php

я нуждаюсь в совете, подскажите логику такой ситуации когда есть неограниченное число категорий, и добавляется новость например в категорию четвертой вложенности, т.е. главная категория - подкатегория1 - подкатегория2 - подкатегория3 - подкатегория4 (сюда добавляется новость) конкретный вопрос в том как правильно сохранять в базу категорию чтоб при выводе данной новости можно было вывести и всю линию категорий (главная категория - подкатегория1 - подкатегория2 - подкатегория3 - подкатегория4) к которым относится эта новость.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут нужно понимание какие запросы к таблице с категориями где использовать. Подробное описание таблицы с такой архитектурой можно найти [здесь](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

Ответ был взят с анго-язычной версии stackoverflow.